# Issue with a regex pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have an issue with regex pattern in C# programming language. My regex pattern doesn't seem to work the way it does on Regexr, I am getting matches even for values not empty or not in the list, where my regex is intended for a specific list of values and an empty string. Below is the piece of code which could demonstrate the essence of the issue:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var pattern = "^(2|4|First|Fourth)?";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        var empty = "";
        var number = "3";
        var yes = "yes";
        var str = "str";

        Console.WriteLine("empty " + regex.IsMatch(empty));
        Console.WriteLine("number " + regex.IsMatch(number));
        Console.WriteLine("yes " + regex.IsMatch(yes));
        Console.WriteLine("string " + regex.IsMatch(str));
    }
}
```

It matches `str` and `3` when it shouldn't. Maybe you could suggest some solution?

Comment: Did you meant to use `^(2|4|First|Fourth)$` instead? Typo?

Comment: By adding `?` at the end whole group become optional so it is always `true`, as @Sweeper said you might want to use `$`.

Comment: can you mention which values should be allowed?

Comment: use \b for word match **@"\b(2|4|First|Fourth)\b"**

Comment: No, isn't a typo, I need a match against those four values 2,4,First,Fourth or match against an empty string. When I've tested with regexr, my proposed regex with ? mark works - it matches against empty or my four values from list, but in C# it is always true

Comment: You should have then empty case also, `"^(|2|4|First|Fourth)$"`, try this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match empty or multiple options(as you mentioned in one of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58335033/issue-with-a-regex-pattern-in-c-sharp/58335413#comment103027264_58335033)), there is the way to go:

```
"^(|2|4|First|Fourth)$"
```

It will match `empty, "2", "4", "First" or "Fourth"`.

---

The problem with the pattern you have proposed is that `?` makes whole group optional so it will match anything :).

Answer (score 2):

Pattern `(2|4|First|Fourth)` will match `2` or `4` or `First` or `Fourth`, you are correct, `^` mathes beginning of the string (so called anchor), but what you are not aware of is `?` operator, which means **match zero or one occurence of a pattern`, so, since it's applied to whole`(2|4|First|Fourth)` pattern, it will match every string.

You can think of this as: match my pattern anchored at the beginning of hte string, but match it zero or one time, **so, also match just beginning of a string**.

See in [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oBE1F/1), that every string is matched (it matches beginning of a string).

Just remove `?` operator or replace it with `$`, which matches end of a string (if it's desired).

To allow also empty string use `^(2|4|First|Fourth|)$` - it will anchor the end of the string with `$` (as mentioned above), also another possibility is added in your alternation, which will allow empt string to match.

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/5oBE1F/2)

Comment: I would suggest adding a more versatile answer, more c# focused. `string[] allowedValues = { string.Empty, "2", "4", "First", "Forth" };`  `foreach(string allowedValue in allowedValues) allowedValue = Regex.Escape(allowedValue);` and finally `string regexExpression = "^(" + string.Join("|", allowedValues) + ")$";`